# Generating pairs from python list

Tags: python

I'm trying generate a bunch of pairs from a list in python --- I figured out a way of doing it using for loops:

```
keys = range(10)
keypairs = list()
for i in range(len(keys)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(keys)):
            keypairs = keypairs + [(keys[i], keys[j])]
```

Is there a more "python style" way of doing this? My method doesn't seem very elegant ...

Comment: @PaoloMoretti That doesn't match OPs desired output. Run his code.

Comment: is your output really what you want - that is different than the worded question?

Answer (score 2):

You want two range loops, one from 0 to n and the inner from each i of the first range + 1 to n using a list comp:

```
n = 10
pairs = [(i, j) for i in range(n) for j in range(i+1, n)]
from pprint import pprint as pp
pp(pairs,compact=True)


[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 8), (0, 9), (1, 2),
 (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5),
 (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7), (3, 8), (3, 9),
 (4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8), (4, 9), (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 9), (6, 7),
 (6, 8), (6, 9), (7, 8), (7, 9), (8, 9)]
```

Which exactly matches your output.

Answer (score 1):

You want to check list comprehension:

```
sorted([(i, j) for j in range(10) for i in range(10) if j > i])
```

Comment: that isnt the same as the questioners output either

Answer (score 1):

I would use [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) for that. Check [combinations_with_replacement](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) and [combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) methods.

And here is the code sample:

```
import itertools
list(itertools.combinations(keys, 2))
```

EDITED: Yes, I noticed that it should be `combinations`, not `combinations_with_replacements`.